# Can you recommend some online resource that have deep insight for the form framework of symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony1

I'm now reading this tutorial:

http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10

But I want to know more of it under the hood,like the design pattern/principles.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for this:

http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/

Comment: Why it still use propel in the document while symfony has by default doctrine enabled?

Comment: Probably because the Symfony guys just havent updated the documentation. In any case, the Propel stuff doesn't really relate to forms directly so just adapt what you see to Doctrine.

Comment: Also,this is not the deep insight I'm seeking,it doesn't mention too much about the most complex part of sfForm:embedded form.I haven't found a tuto that covers the general process to deal with embedded form yet..

Comment: I was never able to find anything easy to read for that either.

Comment: I think the most important thing of symfony is just the form,why don't they write enough documents on that?I'm now stuck here...

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [Advanced Forms](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms) in [More with symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/)  yet?

Comment: It doesn't mention too much about how the bind is done for embedded forms,seems I need to dive into the code implementation...